# CPU emulator written in python (Adjustable Microcode!)

Tags: python, python-3.x, design-patterns, emulator

I've designed and implemented a CPU architecture in one day. Of key architectural details: Processor is supposed to support updatable microcode, Architecture extensions and **Is designed to be implemented sortof like a real CPU** (at least in Logisim Evolution). As I was coding for speed, this 0.5 kiloline monster appeared to haunt me.

### Is there a better way to implement the same functionality?

I have two programs built in. One counts the natural numbers, and the default one outputs the fibonacci sequence. To swap programs, replace `pp(CPU(FIB))` with `pp(CPU(COUNT))`, and vice-versa.

## ISA:

| ID | Opcode | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ADD | A <-- A + B, overflow |
| 1 | JOTO | Jump if overflow, and toggle |
| 2 | LIT | B <-- Literal value following |
| 3 | LOAD | B <-- Mem[I] |
| 4 | STOR | Mem[I] <-- B |
| 5 | SWAP | Swap A and B registers |
| 6 | SWPI | Swap B and I registers |
| 7 | INC | A <-- A + 1, overflow |
| 8 | NOP | Clears overflow |

## cpu.py

```py
from enum import Enum, auto
from pprint import pp
from cpu_flags import (
    ALU_ADD,
    ALU_COMP,
    ALU_INC,
    ALU_LSH,
    ALU_OUT,
    ALU_REG_ENABLE,
    ALU_REG_WRITE,
    ALU_RSH,
    ALU_XOR,
    CLR_OV,
    MEM_ENABLE,
    MEM_WRITE,
    MICRO_RESET,
    PC_ENABLE,
    PC_INC,
    PC_WRITE,
    REG_A_ENABLE,
    REG_A_WRITE,
    REG_B_ENABLE,
    REG_B_WRITE,
    REG_I_ENABLE,
    REG_I_WRITE,
    REG_IR_ENABLE,
    REG_IR_WRITE,
    SET_OV,
)
from cpu_inst import (
    ADD,
    AND,
    CPU_INST,
    INC,
    JOTO,
    LIT,
    LOAD,
    LSH,
    NOP,
    RSH,
    STOR,
    SWAP,
    SWPI,
    XOR,
)
from microcode import JOV_func, microcode
names = {
    ADD: "ADD",
    JOTO: "JOV",
    LIT: "LIT",
    LOAD: "LOAD",
    STOR: "STOR",
    SWAP: "SWAP",
    SWPI: "SWPI",
    INC: "INC",
    NOP: "NOP",
    XOR: "XOR",
    AND: "AND",
    LSH: "LSH",
    RSH: "RSH",
}
class ISA_EXTS(Enum):
    B = 1
    S = 2
    IO = 3
def generate_IA(extensions: set[ISA_EXTS]):
    ia = {x for x in CPU_INST if x.value < 8}
    if ISA_EXTS.B in extensions:
        ia = ia.union((CPU_INST.XOR, CPU_INST.AND))
    if ISA_EXTS.S in extensions:
        ia = ia.union((CPU_INST.LSH, CPU_INST.RSH))
    # if ISA_EXTS.IO in extensions:
    #     ia = ia.union((CPU_INST.IN, CPU_INST.OUT))
    return sorted(ia)
MAX_VALUE = 1 << 300
isa_exts = {}
isa = generate_IA(isa_exts)
def CPU(MEM):
    prog_counter = -1
    reg_a = 0
    reg_b = 0
    reg_i = 0
    reg_alu = 0
    alu_out = 0
    overflow = False
    jumped = False
    u = 0
    instruction = NOP
    new_instruction = NOP
    old_bus = 0
    bus = 0
    flags = {}
    inst_set = microcode[instruction]
    while prog_counter < len(MEM):
        # microcode[new_instruction]
        old_bus = bus
        bus = 0
        # if prog_counter >= 18:
        #     print(u)
        flags = inst_set[u]
        # if u == 0:
        # print(f"BUS:{bus}")
        # print(
        #     f"pc:{prog_counter} {names[instruction]}, a:{reg_a}, b:{reg_b}, i:{reg_i}, o:{overflow}"
        # )
        # print(f"u:{u}, mem:{MEM[prog_counter - 2 : prog_counter + 3]}")
        # print(flags)
        if MICRO_RESET in flags:
            u = 0
            if not jumped:
                instruction = new_instruction
            else:
                instruction = MEM[prog_counter]
            inst_set = microcode[instruction]
            if inst_set == JOV_func:
                inst_set = JOV_func(overflow)
            continue
        if PC_INC in flags:
            prog_counter += 1
        if PC_ENABLE in flags:
            bus = prog_counter
        if REG_IR_ENABLE in flags:
            bus = instruction
        if MEM_ENABLE in flags:
            # print(f"READMEM, mem:{MEM[old_bus - 2 : old_bus + 3]}")
            bus = MEM[old_bus]
        if REG_A_ENABLE in flags:
            bus = reg_a
        if REG_B_ENABLE in flags:
            bus = reg_b
        if REG_I_ENABLE in flags:
            bus = reg_i
        if ALU_REG_ENABLE in flags:
            bus = reg_alu
        if ALU_OUT in flags:
            bus = alu_out
        if PC_WRITE in flags:
            # print("JUMP", bus)
            jumped = True
            prog_counter = bus
        if REG_IR_WRITE in flags:
            new_instruction = bus
        if MEM_WRITE in flags:
            MEM[old_bus] = bus
            # print(f"WRITE MEM, mem:{MEM[old_bus - 2 : old_bus + 4]}")
        if REG_A_WRITE in flags:
            reg_a = bus
        if REG_B_WRITE in flags:
            reg_b = bus
        if REG_I_WRITE in flags:
            reg_i = bus
        if ALU_REG_WRITE in flags:
            reg_alu = bus
        if ALU_ADD in flags:
            b = reg_alu + bus
            if b > MAX_VALUE:
                overflow = True
                b %= MAX_VALUE
            alu_out = b
        if ALU_XOR in flags:
            alu_out = reg_alu ^ bus
        if ALU_INC in flags:
            alu_out = reg_alu + 1
            if alu_out >= MAX_VALUE:
                overflow = True
                alu_out %= MAX_VALUE
        if CLR_OV in flags:
            overflow = False
        if SET_OV in flags:
            overflow = True
        # ALU_COMP = CPU_FLAG.ALU_COMP
        # ALU_AND = CPU_FLAG.ALU_AND
        # ALU_LSH = CPU_FLAG.ALU_LSH
        u += 1
    return MEM
# Normal instruction
# FETCH, EXECUTE, INC
def create_prog(prog, length=1000):
    return prog + (length - len(prog)) * [0]
# Fibonacci
FIB = create_prog(
    [
        LIT,
        65,
        SWPI,  # 0, 0, 65
        INC,  # 1, 0
        SWAP,  # 0, 1
        STOR,
        SWAP,  # 1, 0
        LOAD,  # 1, 1
        ADD,  # 2, 1, 64
        SWAP,  # 1, 2, 64
        STOR,  #
        LIT,
        28,
        JOTO,  # Terminate if overflow
        NOP,
        LOAD,
        SWPI,  # a + b, 64, b
        SWAP,  # 64, a + b, b
        INC,  # 65, a + b, b
        SWAP,
        SWPI,  # a + b, b, 65
        STOR,  # Stored A+B at next I
        LIT,
        1000,
        JOTO,
        LIT,
        7,
        JOTO,
        LIT,
        0,
        STOR,
        LIT,
        1000,
        JOTO,
        JOTO,
    ],
    length=512,
)
COUNT = create_prog(
    [
        LIT,
        24,
        SWPI,
        LIT,
        0,
        INC,  #   1,  0, 16
        SWAP,  #  0,  1, 16
        STOR,  # Write to loc 16
        SWPI,  #  0, 16, 1
        SWAP,  # 16,  0, 1
        INC,  #  17,  0, 1
        SWAP,  #  0, 17, 1
        SWPI,  #  0,  1, 17
        SWAP,  #  1,  0, 17
        LIT,
        1000,
        JOTO,
        LIT,
        3,
        JOTO,
    ]
)
pp(CPU(FIB))
```

## cpu_inst.py

```py
from enum import Enum
class CPU_INST(Enum):
    ADD = 0
    JOV = 1
    LIT = 2
    LOAD = 3
    STOR = 4
    SWAP = 5
    SWPI = 6
    INC = 7
    NOP = 8
    XOR = 9
    AND = 10
    LSH = 11
    RSH = 12
    def __lt__(self, o):
        return self.value < o.value
ADD = 0
JOTO = 1
LIT = 2
LOAD = 3
STOR = 4
SWAP = 5
SWPI = 6
INC = 7
NOP = 8
XOR = 9
AND = 10
LSH = 11
RSH = 12
# cpu_flags.py
from enum import Enum, auto
class CPU_FLAG(Enum):
    MEM_ENABLE = auto()
    MEM_WRITE = auto()
    MICRO_RESET = auto()
    PC_INC = auto()
    PC_ENABLE = auto()
    PC_WRITE = auto()
    REG_IR_ENABLE = auto()
    REG_IR_WRITE = auto()
    REG_A_ENABLE = auto()
    REG_A_WRITE = auto()
    REG_B_ENABLE = auto()
    REG_B_WRITE = auto()
    REG_I_ENABLE = auto()
    REG_I_WRITE = auto()
    ALU_REG_ENABLE = auto()
    ALU_REG_WRITE = auto()
    ALU_COMP = auto()
    ALU_ADD = auto()
    ALU_AND = auto()
    ALU_XOR = auto()
    ALU_INC = auto()
    ALU_LSH = auto()
    ALU_RSH = auto()
    ALU_OUT = auto()
    CLR_OV = auto()
    SET_OV = auto()
MEM_ENABLE = CPU_FLAG.MEM_ENABLE
MEM_WRITE = CPU_FLAG.MEM_WRITE
MICRO_RESET = CPU_FLAG.MICRO_RESET
PC_INC = CPU_FLAG.PC_INC
PC_ENABLE = CPU_FLAG.PC_ENABLE
PC_WRITE = CPU_FLAG.PC_WRITE
REG_IR_ENABLE = CPU_FLAG.REG_IR_ENABLE
REG_IR_WRITE = CPU_FLAG.REG_IR_WRITE
REG_A_ENABLE = CPU_FLAG.REG_A_ENABLE
REG_A_WRITE = CPU_FLAG.REG_A_WRITE
REG_B_ENABLE = CPU_FLAG.REG_B_ENABLE
REG_B_WRITE = CPU_FLAG.REG_B_WRITE
REG_I_ENABLE = CPU_FLAG.REG_I_ENABLE
REG_I_WRITE = CPU_FLAG.REG_I_WRITE
ALU_REG_ENABLE = CPU_FLAG.ALU_REG_ENABLE
ALU_REG_WRITE = CPU_FLAG.ALU_REG_WRITE
ALU_COMP = CPU_FLAG.ALU_COMP
ALU_ADD = CPU_FLAG.ALU_ADD
ALU_XOR = CPU_FLAG.ALU_XOR
ALU_AND = CPU_FLAG.ALU_AND
ALU_LSH = CPU_FLAG.ALU_LSH
ALU_RSH = CPU_FLAG.ALU_RSH
ALU_INC = CPU_FLAG.ALU_INC
ALU_OUT = CPU_FLAG.ALU_OUT
CLR_OV = CPU_FLAG.CLR_OV
SET_OV = CPU_FLAG.SET_OV
```

## microcode.py

```py
from cpu_flags import (
    MEM_ENABLE,
    MEM_WRITE,
    MICRO_RESET,
    PC_INC,
    PC_ENABLE,
    PC_WRITE,
    REG_IR_ENABLE,
    REG_IR_WRITE,
    REG_A_ENABLE,
    REG_A_WRITE,
    REG_B_ENABLE,
    REG_B_WRITE,
    REG_I_ENABLE,
    REG_I_WRITE,
    ALU_REG_ENABLE,
    ALU_REG_WRITE,
    ALU_COMP,
    ALU_ADD,
    ALU_XOR,
    ALU_INC,
    ALU_LSH,
    ALU_RSH,
    ALU_OUT,
    CLR_OV,
    SET_OV,
)
from cpu_inst import (
    ADD,
    JOTO,
    LIT,
    LOAD,
    STOR,
    SWAP,
    SWPI,
    INC,
    NOP,
    XOR,
    AND,
    LSH,
    RSH,
)
# Jump if overflow, toggle overflow
def JOV_func(overflow):
    if overflow:
        return [
            {REG_B_ENABLE, PC_WRITE},
            {CLR_OV},
            {MICRO_RESET},
        ]
    return [
        # No Overflow {}
        {PC_INC},
        {PC_ENABLE},
        {MEM_ENABLE, REG_IR_WRITE, SET_OV},
        {MICRO_RESET},
    ]
# ADD operation
# FETCH, EXECUTE, STORE/INC
microcode = {
    ADD: [
        {REG_A_ENABLE, ALU_REG_WRITE, CLR_OV},
        {REG_B_ENABLE, ALU_ADD},
        {ALU_OUT, REG_A_WRITE},
        {PC_INC},
        {PC_ENABLE},
        {MEM_ENABLE, REG_IR_WRITE},
        {MICRO_RESET},
    ],
    JOTO: JOV_func,
    LIT: [
        {PC_INC},
        {PC_ENABLE},
        {MEM_ENABLE, REG_B_WRITE},
        {PC_INC},
        {PC_ENABLE},
        {MEM_ENABLE, REG_IR_WRITE},
        {MICRO_RESET},
    ],
    LOAD: [
        {REG_I_ENABLE},
        {MEM_ENABLE, REG_B_WRITE},
        {PC_INC},
        {PC_ENABLE},
        {MEM_ENABLE, REG_IR_WRITE},
        {MICRO_RESET},
    ],
    STOR: [
        {REG_I_ENABLE},
        {MEM_WRITE, REG_B_ENABLE},
        {PC_INC},
        {PC_ENABLE},
        {MEM_ENABLE, REG_IR_WRITE},
        {MICRO_RESET},
    ],
    SWAP: [
        {ALU_REG_WRITE, REG_A_ENABLE},
        {REG_A_WRITE, REG_B_ENABLE},
        {REG_B_WRITE, ALU_REG_ENABLE},
        {PC_INC},
        {PC_ENABLE},
        {MEM_ENABLE, REG_IR_WRITE},
        {MICRO_RESET},
    ],
    SWPI: [
        {ALU_REG_WRITE, REG_B_ENABLE},
        {REG_B_WRITE, REG_I_ENABLE},
        {REG_I_WRITE, ALU_REG_ENABLE},
        {PC_INC},
        {PC_ENABLE},
        {MEM_ENABLE, REG_IR_WRITE},
        {MICRO_RESET},
    ],
    INC: [
        {REG_A_ENABLE, ALU_REG_WRITE, CLR_OV},
        {ALU_INC},
        {ALU_OUT, REG_A_WRITE},
        {PC_INC},
        {PC_ENABLE},
        {MEM_ENABLE, REG_IR_WRITE},
        {MICRO_RESET},
    ],
    NOP: [
        {PC_INC, CLR_OV},
        {PC_ENABLE},
        {MEM_ENABLE, REG_IR_WRITE},
        {MICRO_RESET},
    ],
}
```

Comment: Is your max value really 300 bits wide?

Comment: No, because python!

Comment: **Note**: edits to the question may complain about unformatted code. Please, rollback my edit to the table to move forward. [Additional information is available on Meta.](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10898)

Comment: `NOP` seems to be the wrong opcode name. Consider calling it `CLRV`, for clear overflow.

Answer (score 2):

This is a von Neumann machine, which is risky. It introduces the possibility of a whole category of bugs that by definition cannot exist on a Harvard machine. If you're able, rewrite to represent the latter.

If you're going for realism, it is not particularly realistic to have a CPU that represents 300-bit integers natively. For one, that's impractically large for the native word size; and also even if it were implemented, it would almost always be a power of 2 (i.e. 256 instead of 300).

You have namespace problems. The long lists of CPU flags and CPU instructions should not exist in the global namespace at any point.

Don't use `pprint.pp`; it was a bad decision for Python to offer that alias in the first place. Just use `pprint.pprint`.

`names` is unused so delete it.

You need more spaces between class and function definitions; use a PEP8 linter.

You need more typehints, and some of your existing typehints are incorrect. For example, you set `isa_exts = {}` to an empty dictionary but then later treat it as a set.

You have a lot of dead code in comments. This is what source control is for: commit old versions, and then delete (not comment) dead code; it will always be in the history for reference.

`CPU` and `MEM` (a function and parameter name, respectively) should both be lowercase. Again a PEP8 linter will help with this.

Representing the entire CPU state in a scattering of local variables in `CPU()` is not a very convenient way to represent state. Consider instead a state class.

`CPU()` should be broken up. Among other pieces, you could convert the repeated `if in flags` to a loop over all possible flags and a lookup of callables.

Comments like this:

```py
# Normal instruction
# FETCH, EXECUTE, INC
def create_prog(prog, length=1000):
```

need to be converted to docstrings:

```py
def create_prog(prog: Memory, length: int = 1000) -> Memory:
    """Normal instruction
    FETCH, EXECUTE, INC"""
```

Your program memory, by your current design, has mixed types - instruction enums, and integers. This is not a great idea. Go all-or-nothing: have either a sequence of instruction objects tied to their arguments (like `Literal(65)`) and no bare integers in memory; or after a compilation step, have *only* integers in memory that represent the instruction opcodes and arguments, as would exist in real life.

Don't `pp(CPU(FIB))` without a `__main__` guard.

### Suggested

This addresses some (certainly not all) of the above:

```py
from enum import Enum, auto
from pprint import pprint
from typing import Callable


class CpuInst(Enum):
    ADD = 0
    JOV = 1
    JOTO = JOV
    LIT = 2
    LOAD = 3
    STOR = 4
    SWAP = 5
    SWPI = 6
    INC = 7
    NOP = 8
    XOR = 9
    AND = 10
    LSH = 11
    RSH = 12

    def __lt__(self, o: 'CpuInst') -> bool:
        return self.value < o.value


class CpuFlag(Enum):
    MEM_ENABLE = auto()
    MEM_WRITE = auto()
    MICRO_RESET = auto()
    PC_INC = auto()
    PC_ENABLE = auto()
    PC_WRITE = auto()
    REG_IR_ENABLE = auto()
    REG_IR_WRITE = auto()
    REG_A_ENABLE = auto()
    REG_A_WRITE = auto()
    REG_B_ENABLE = auto()
    REG_B_WRITE = auto()
    REG_I_ENABLE = auto()
    REG_I_WRITE = auto()
    ALU_REG_ENABLE = auto()
    ALU_REG_WRITE = auto()
    ALU_COMP = auto()
    ALU_ADD = auto()
    ALU_AND = auto()
    ALU_XOR = auto()
    ALU_INC = auto()
    ALU_LSH = auto()
    ALU_RSH = auto()
    ALU_OUT = auto()
    CLR_OV = auto()
    SET_OV = auto()


class IsaExts(Enum):
    B = 1
    S = 2
    IO = 3


def generate_ia(extensions: set[IsaExts]) -> list[CpuInst]:
    ia = {x for x in CpuInst if x.value < 8}
    if IsaExts.B in extensions:
        ia |= {CpuInst.XOR, CpuInst.AND}
    if IsaExts.S in extensions:
        ia |= {CpuInst.LSH, CpuInst.RSH}
    return sorted(ia)


MAX_VALUE = 1 << 300
ISA_EXTS = set()
ISA = generate_ia(ISA_EXTS)

CpuFlagSets = tuple[set[CpuFlag], ...]
Memory = list[CpuInst | int]


def jov_func(overflow: bool) -> CpuFlagSets:
    """Jump if overflow, toggle overflow"""
    f = CpuFlag

    if overflow:
        return (
            {f.REG_B_ENABLE, f.PC_WRITE},
            {f.CLR_OV},
            {f.MICRO_RESET},
        )
    return (
        # No Overflow {}
        {f.PC_INC},
        {f.PC_ENABLE},
        {f.MEM_ENABLE, f.REG_IR_WRITE, f.SET_OV},
        {f.MICRO_RESET},
    )


def make_microcode() -> dict[
    CpuInst,
    CpuFlagSets | Callable[[bool], CpuFlagSets],
]:
    i = CpuInst
    f = CpuFlag

    return {
        i.ADD: (
            {f.REG_A_ENABLE, f.ALU_REG_WRITE, f.CLR_OV},
            {f.REG_B_ENABLE, f.ALU_ADD},
            {f.ALU_OUT, f.REG_A_WRITE},
            {f.PC_INC},
            {f.PC_ENABLE},
            {f.MEM_ENABLE, f.REG_IR_WRITE},
            {f.MICRO_RESET},
        ),
        i.JOV: jov_func,
        i.LIT: (
            {f.PC_INC},
            {f.PC_ENABLE},
            {f.MEM_ENABLE, f.REG_B_WRITE},
            {f.PC_INC},
            {f.PC_ENABLE},
            {f.MEM_ENABLE, f.REG_IR_WRITE},
            {f.MICRO_RESET},
        ),
        i.LOAD: (
            {f.REG_I_ENABLE},
            {f.MEM_ENABLE, f.REG_B_WRITE},
            {f.PC_INC},
            {f.PC_ENABLE},
            {f.MEM_ENABLE, f.REG_IR_WRITE},
            {f.MICRO_RESET},
        ),
        i.STOR: (
            {f.REG_I_ENABLE},
            {f.MEM_WRITE, f.REG_B_ENABLE},
            {f.PC_INC},
            {f.PC_ENABLE},
            {f.MEM_ENABLE, f.REG_IR_WRITE},
            {f.MICRO_RESET},
        ),
        i.SWAP: (
            {f.ALU_REG_WRITE, f.REG_A_ENABLE},
            {f.REG_A_WRITE, f.REG_B_ENABLE},
            {f.REG_B_WRITE, f.ALU_REG_ENABLE},
            {f.PC_INC},
            {f.PC_ENABLE},
            {f.MEM_ENABLE, f.REG_IR_WRITE},
            {f.MICRO_RESET},
        ),
        i.SWPI: (
            {f.ALU_REG_WRITE, f.REG_B_ENABLE},
            {f.REG_B_WRITE, f.REG_I_ENABLE},
            {f.REG_I_WRITE, f.ALU_REG_ENABLE},
            {f.PC_INC},
            {f.PC_ENABLE},
            {f.MEM_ENABLE, f.REG_IR_WRITE},
            {f.MICRO_RESET},
        ),
        i.INC: (
            {f.REG_A_ENABLE, f.ALU_REG_WRITE, f.CLR_OV},
            {f.ALU_INC},
            {f.ALU_OUT, f.REG_A_WRITE},
            {f.PC_INC},
            {f.PC_ENABLE},
            {f.MEM_ENABLE, f.REG_IR_WRITE},
            {f.MICRO_RESET},
        ),
        i.NOP: (
            {f.PC_INC, f.CLR_OV},
            {f.PC_ENABLE},
            {f.MEM_ENABLE, f.REG_IR_WRITE},
            {f.MICRO_RESET},
        ),
    }


MICROCODE = make_microcode()


def cpu(mem: Memory) -> Memory:
    prog_counter = -1
    reg_a = 0
    reg_b = 0
    reg_i = 0
    reg_alu = 0
    alu_out = 0
    overflow = False
    jumped = False
    u = 0
    instruction = CpuInst.NOP
    new_instruction = CpuInst.NOP
    bus = 0
    inst_set = MICROCODE[instruction]
    f = CpuFlag

    while prog_counter < len(mem):
        old_bus = bus
        bus = 0
        flags = inst_set[u]

        if f.MICRO_RESET in flags:
            u = 0
            if not jumped:
                instruction = new_instruction
            else:
                instruction = mem[prog_counter]
            inst_set = MICROCODE[instruction]
            if inst_set == jov_func:
                inst_set = jov_func(overflow)
            continue
        if f.PC_INC in flags:
            prog_counter += 1
        if f.PC_ENABLE in flags:
            bus = prog_counter
        if f.REG_IR_ENABLE in flags:
            bus = instruction
        if f.MEM_ENABLE in flags:
            bus = mem[old_bus]
        if f.REG_A_ENABLE in flags:
            bus = reg_a
        if f.REG_B_ENABLE in flags:
            bus = reg_b
        if f.REG_I_ENABLE in flags:
            bus = reg_i
        if f.ALU_REG_ENABLE in flags:
            bus = reg_alu
        if f.ALU_OUT in flags:
            bus = alu_out
        if f.PC_WRITE in flags:
            jumped = True
            prog_counter = bus
        if f.REG_IR_WRITE in flags:
            new_instruction = bus
        if f.MEM_WRITE in flags:
            mem[old_bus] = bus
        if f.REG_A_WRITE in flags:
            reg_a = bus
        if f.REG_B_WRITE in flags:
            reg_b = bus
        if f.REG_I_WRITE in flags:
            reg_i = bus
        if f.ALU_REG_WRITE in flags:
            reg_alu = bus
        if f.ALU_ADD in flags:
            b = reg_alu + bus
            if b > MAX_VALUE:
                overflow = True
                b %= MAX_VALUE
            alu_out = b
        if f.ALU_XOR in flags:
            alu_out = reg_alu ^ bus
        if f.ALU_INC in flags:
            alu_out = reg_alu + 1
            if alu_out >= MAX_VALUE:
                overflow = True
                alu_out %= MAX_VALUE
        if f.CLR_OV in flags:
            overflow = False
        if f.SET_OV in flags:
            overflow = True
        u += 1

    return mem


def create_prog(prog: Memory, length: int = 1000) -> Memory:
    """Normal instruction
    FETCH, EXECUTE, INC"""
    return prog + (length - len(prog)) * [0]


def make_fibonacci() -> Memory:
    i = CpuInst

    return create_prog(
        prog=[
            i.LIT,
            65,
            i.SWPI,  # 0, 0, 65
            i.INC,  # 1, 0
            i.SWAP,  # 0, 1
            i.STOR,
            i.SWAP,  # 1, 0
            i.LOAD,  # 1, 1
            i.ADD,  # 2, 1, 64
            i.SWAP,  # 1, 2, 64
            i.STOR,  #
            i.LIT,
            28,
            i.JOTO,  # Terminate if overflow
            i.NOP,
            i.LOAD,
            i.SWPI,  # a + b, 64, b
            i.SWAP,  # 64, a + b, b
            i.INC,  # 65, a + b, b
            i.SWAP,
            i.SWPI,  # a + b, b, 65
            i.STOR,  # Stored A+B at next I
            i.LIT,
            1000,
            i.JOTO,
            i.LIT,
            7,
            i.JOTO,
            i.LIT,
            0,
            i.STOR,
            i.LIT,
            1000,
            i.JOTO,
            i.JOTO,
        ],
        length=512,
    )


def make_count() -> Memory:
    i = CpuInst

    return create_prog([
        i.LIT,
        24,
        i.SWPI,
        i.LIT,
        0,
        i.INC,   #  1,  0, 16
        i.SWAP,  #  0,  1, 16
        i.STOR,  # Write to loc 16
        i.SWPI,  #  0, 16,  1
        i.SWAP,  # 16,  0,  1
        i.INC,   # 17,  0,  1
        i.SWAP,  #  0, 17,  1
        i.SWPI,  #  0,  1, 17
        i.SWAP,  #  1,  0, 17
        i.LIT,
        1000,
        i.JOTO,
        i.LIT,
        3,
        i.JOTO,
    ])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pprint(cpu(make_fibonacci()))
```